# How to add s3:ListBucket permission to my S3 bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name_here/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried changing my action line to -

```
"Action":
[
"s3:GetObject",
"s3:ListBucket",
],
```

but still no luck! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets were just a bit off. In the future you can use the [policy generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) to help create policies that require more complex parameters. Something similar to the following should help with your requirement.

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1426519951124",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1426519948229",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name_here/",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```